# Send emails automatically to a list of contacts with specific attachment

Tags: email, contacts

I have the task of sending a standard email to a list of people. The hard part is that each email has a specific foto attached. My list is like this:

1. John Snow, john@winterfell.com, johnSnow.jpg
2. Aria Stark, aria@winterfell.com, ariaStark.jpg

And my email looks like this:

```
Dear <name> <surname>, 
bla bla bla. Find attachment <fileName>

thanks

<attachment>
```

The list contains 150 people. How can I program or send this email? Is there an app or a script for doing this? or any online service?

For your reference: I know a bit of php, python, JS and shell scripting, maybe that helps.

THANKS!

PD. I asked at madmimi.com, but they can't attach specific files depending on the contact. All emails would have the same attachment, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to play with standard MacOS X tool - Automator.
Not a big expert myself :), but I know it helps in exactly this type of tasks.
Here are couple of useful basic tutorials on Automator:

- http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/learn.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z56PBanBSx4